# Use goto statements to explicitly show the flow control through the loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, goto, flow-control

I am supposed to take the following program fragment and use goto statements to show the flow control through the the loop:

```
for ( int i = n; i > 0; i-- ) {
    if ( x != A[i] )
    break;
}
```

I realize that goto statements should be avoided, but this is what the question is asking for. I think this is what it should be, so that the flow control is shown through the loop:

```
for ( int i = n; i > 0; i-- ) {
    if ( x != A[i] )
    goto xValue;
    break;
}

xValue: cout << "The value of x: \n" << x;
```

Is this correct? I am not positive about whether to place the goto statement before or after the break statement.

Comment: Q: Why don't you delete the "break"?  Q: Shouldn't you also replace for "for" loop with a goto?

Comment: So, you're saying replace `for` with `goto`, and remove the break statement entirely? @paulsm4

Comment: I  too would remove the for loop and replace it with explicit gotos. A for is just an init block, followed by an exit condition (which is basically an if and a goto), followed by a body, an increment operation and a goto back to the exit condition check. Obviously, just for the assignment ;)

Comment: Is this what you were thinking about? @paulsm4 @A.Chiesa  `goto xValue ( int i = n; i > 0; i--) if ( x !=A[i] ) goto xValue;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the correct solution for this question:

```
xValue ( int i = n; i > 0; i-- )
      If ( x !=  A[i] )
        goto xValue;
```